# Leaflet popup with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popupwindow

I am trying to show pop up on markers that are read from SQL table. I managed to read one field, but I need it to read more than one field (`first_name`, `Family_name`, `Health_con`...etc.).

```
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )  {
            caseData.push ({
                id: data[i].id, 
                first_name: data[i].first_name,
                family_name: data[i].family_name,   
                health_con: data[i].health_con,
                nin: data[i].nin,
                notes: data[i].notes,
                lat: data[i].lat, 
                lon: data[i].lon
            }); 
        }
        plotCases()
    })

    event.preventDefault();
});
});

function plotCases()    {

 // Loop through caseData to create marker at each location 
   for (var i = 0; i < caseData.length; i++)    { 
    var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(caseData[i].lat, caseData[i].lon);
    var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
    mymap.addLayer(marker);
    marker.bindPopup(caseData[i].health_con); }}  <<< here
```

I am trying to show more than one field in the popup info window.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO!

You seem to also be new to JavaScript and probably programming in general.

Leaflet `bindPopup` method accepts a *string* as argument.
You need to *concatenate* the string values of your "fields": see the "Concatenating strings" section of the MDN guide about manipulating strings:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings
In short: use the `+` operator `str1 + str2`

You may also be interested in that post on GIS StackExchange:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169976/how-to-iterate-through-the-attributes-of-a-feature-in-leaflet

Answer (score 1):

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'if-you-need-a-class'})
.setContent('<div class="if-you-need-div">'+
'<h3>' + caseData[i].health_con + '</\h3>'+
'<p><b>' + caseData[i].notes + '</b><br>'+
'<b>' + caseData[i].family_name + '</b><br>'+
'</\p>'+
'</\div>');

var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(caseData[i].lat, caseData[i].lon);
var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation).bindPopup(popup);

mymap.addLayer(marker);
```

Should work as expected. For visibility I'm using multiple line but you can put everyting in a single line like this :

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'if-you-need-a-class'})
.setContent('<div class="if-you-need-div"><h3>' + caseData[i].health_con + '</\h3>[...]</\div>');
```

`L.popup` give you more settings if you need to add a classname but you can still use `marker.bindPopup(your-string-here);`